# Is there any way to activate IntelliSense for TypeScript files in github.dev?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web, github, intellisense

This morning I came across **github.dev**.

It looks very promising, but what I'd *really* like to use it for is **TypeScript with active IntelliSense**.

I can see that **github.dev** can create new `.ts` files.

But, as an in-browser code editor, can it activate the sophisticated kind of IntelliSense for `.ts` files that the desktop version of **Visual Studio Code** takes advantage of?

Or, instead, is *syntax highlighting* the limit of **github.dev**'s capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

> as an in-browser code editor, can **github.dev** activate the sophisticated kind of IntelliSense for `.ts` files that the desktop version of **Visual Studio Code** takes advantage of?

It's not obvious that it can.

There *are* extensions that can be activated for **github.dev**.

But none - as far as I can see - which can activate standard **TypeScript IntelliSense** for `.ts` files.

---

However, all is not lost.

For those (like me) looking for a lightweight version of *Visual Studio Code* which runs in the browser, it turns out there is an slightly newer alternative to **github.dev**, which *does* feature **TypeScript with active IntelliSense**:

- **vscode.dev** (https://vscode.dev/)

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/10/20/vscode-dev